# Adding 2 value using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, input

I am trying to write a an input code that can put 2 output all together and add it up. The code is below;

```
import numpy as np
x, y = input("Insert value").split()

print(x)
print(y)
print(np.add(x,y))
```

Output:

```
4
3

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UFuncTypeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-d7826b294c37> in <module>
      4 print(x)
      5 print(y)
----> 6 print(np.add(x,y))

UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U1'), dtype('<U1')) -> dtype('<U1'
```

Can anyone help this?

Comment: This is not an appropriate use of `np.add()`, which takes array-like arguments and adds them element-wise. What you need to do is convert your string inputs to a numeric type and then perform addition via the `+` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple. Just add int() on every variable and use '+' operator.

```
import numpy as np
x, y = input("Insert value").split()

print(x)
print(y)
print(int(x) + int(y))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not told Python to convert your inputs, which are strings, into numbers.  If your typecast to integers, your code will work:

```
import numpy as np
x, y = input("Insert value").split()

print(x)
print(y)
print(np.add(int(x),int(y)))
```

Comment: Already tried, still error.

Comment: Is it the exact same error?

Comment: Yes. I tried to change it to ```int(x) + int(y)``` and it works well.